# how to call function in DLL or Shared LIbrary (in oracle external procedure)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Oracle provides external procedure.

External procedure allow oracle use the user's library(DLL or .so) instead of PL/SQL function.

Oracle create the extproc that load DLL(or .so) and call function dynamically.

I wonder how to call function dynamically.

To call function in dll dynamically, i know that use the loadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() and need to casting function pointer.

But oracle doesn't know function prototype and can not casting the function pointer at runtime.

So, how to call function in DLL(or .so) without function prototype at runtime?

Comment: Why do you need to call an external function dynamically?  It's generally a good idea to keep extprocs locked down as it avoids complications; people often perceive them as a bit of a security risk (because they can be).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm just curious. I know that i need function prototype and function pointer casting to call function in dll dynamically. So i post this question